# C# strange string behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on project using ChromeDriver and some strange behaviour occurs while trying to insert value in input field.

```
            var loginNameElement = GetUserNameElement(driver);
            string value = "test@sss";
            loginNameElement.SendKeys(value);
```

This will result in some strange string like

```
"testvaluesss"
or
"testsss"
or even printing own code
testvaluesss; Console.Writeline(value);
```

If I run this code on my desktop computer with windows 10 it works and insert "test@sss".

But if I run this on Windows Server 2012 R2 this strange behaviour occurs.

Does anyone has some idea why this happens?

Thank you

Comment: "*C# strange string behaviour*" - this is not the best title...

Comment: WHat's your keyboard layout? Is it English or something different? Do you have the latest version of the driver?

Comment: See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1771 It's likely a problem with JS on your site, slow machine, sending them too early etc.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18415/selenium-sendkeys-not-inserting-value-into-textbox/20736

Comment: @andI'msureI'mmissingsome It was problem with the keyboard layout! After switching to ENG layout everything seems to work. Thank you so much!